# Access inode table to list all filenames

Tags: c, filesystems, inode, cifs

I would like to know the most efficient way to list the filenames on a Posix system. Doing either:

```
$ ls -R
```

Or:

```
$ find /
```

Or:

```
$ du /
```

Or 100 other variations (links abound on StackOverflow/ServerFault about various ways to do this). However, this is way too slow on the filesystem I am on, [cifs](https://cifs.com/) -- for example, I have currently been running the `ls -R` for about two days (it takes about 50 hours to complete -- there are tons of files and directories on the system -- several petabytes worth).

So I am wondering if this can be done at a lower-level, hopefully in C. to list out the filenames from the `inode` database (example [here](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/winter08/cs111/scribe/12/index.html)). I don't need a recursive lookup of the entire path, but only the top-level `name | filename` -- and I would build out everything else manually. Is there a way to do this so that hopefully instead of taking ~50 hours to do an `ls` command with the billions of recursive lookups (yes, it does get cached after successive runs, but not most of it on the first run) can the inode database itself be dumped?

An an example, perhaps something like:

```
#filename,inode
myfile.mov,1234
myotherfile.csv,92033
```

But the main point here --and why I asked this question -- is speed not actually a command in order to do the above (such as `$ ls -iR`).

Comment: `ls -i` does dump the inode numbers as well but I'm guessing that's not what you want. Could you also share an example of what you would expect from the output of a sample directory tree? I am unable to understand the `don't need a recursive lookup of the entire path, but only the top-level ` bit.

Comment: @Zoso I just added an update. I mean just the filename and not the whole path, so, `myfile.mov` instead of `/mnt/something/somewhere/path/to/myfile.mov`

Comment: @Zoso regarding `ls -i` -- that's fine I only care about speed so whatever is required to do that.

Comment: The inodes don't contain the filename.  Filenames exist *only* in directory entries.  This is what allows multiple hard links to point to the same physical file.

Comment: @David542 Have you tried the [`getdents`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) API which retrieves the directory entries from the kernel? I think that should at least give the inode numbers. It is what `ls` uses under the hood

Comment: Actually, cifs is a network filesystem, so of course it will be slow because everything is a network request.  So you probably want to run the `ls` command directly on the server that's physically hosting the disk.

Comment: @Zoso our of curiosity, what would be the difference between using `getdents` (such as in the example they show on the man page) and using `ls`? Does ls use a bunch more unnecessary syscalls or something?

Comment: @dbush I have the volume mounted on my debian server but that's it. I don't have / won't be able to have any further access.

Comment: @David542 One primary difference would be that it does `write`s to the console (or some other file if piped), which wouldn't be necessary for you and can be maintained in memory (I _hope_?) . I have absolutely no performance numbers to back this up though. Would doing that fit your usage?

Comment: @Zoso no idea -- but I'll try it and see if that fits the bill! If it does, maybe I can post an answer with it, fingers crossed.

Comment: @Zoso do you know where the syscalls would be in something like this? https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c. It seems they're abstracted or imported, as when I search syscall or gedents I don't find anything. Finally, one more thing is I don't have `sudo` access so I cannot do a ptrace to see what syscalls are being done, for example, on ls.

Comment: @David542 I doubt it would be directly using the syscalls but instead uses [`readdir`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L2988) which in turn is the glibc wrapper over `getdents`.

Comment: @David542 Also this reminds me, `ls` uses the [`ioctl`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L1943) call to [`TIOCGWNSZ`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) for querying the terminal size to get line width. That's one more thing you would be shaving off in your code.

Comment: @David542 Also for the  sudo problem, I believe you could use [`strace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to at least trace the process started by your userID as `strace ls <path> -o dump_calls.txt`.

Comment: The system calls are probably deferring to the cifs driver, which is talking over the network to the remote server and performing the associated encryption / decryption.  If there's any way you can run the commands directly on the remote server that should *easily* give you a big speed boost.

Comment: @Zoso I posted an example code (probably bad code, but working code, I'm quite a beginner at C). How does that look? I'm going to start benchmarking it shortly but it'll take some time and I'll update the answer then.

Comment: @dbush -- yea, the `cifs` call takes about 99.99% of the time, so I think I need to figure out how/if to change how I'm accessing it.

Comment: @David542 Looks fine. Add some error checking for `fopen` in `main()`, Not sure about the length `char path[400]`, probably bump it up?.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to directly use [`getdents`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) recursively. I will update timings of this shortly to compare it to `ls` and the other standard unix utils:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define handle_error(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct linux_dirent {
    unsigned long  d_ino;
    off_t          d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char           d_name[];
};

void print_files(char* dir, FILE* out)
{
    // open the file
    int fd = open(dir, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
    if (fd == -1) handle_error("Error opening file.\n");

    // grab a buffer to read the file data
    #define BUF_SIZE (1024*1024*1)
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * BUF_SIZE);
    if (buffer == NULL) handle_error("Error malloc.\n");

    // do the getdents syscall writing to buffer
    int num_read = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    if (num_read == -1) handle_error("Error getdents syscall.\n");
    close(fd);

    for (long buffer_position = 0; buffer_position < num_read;) {

        struct linux_dirent *d = (struct linux_dirent *) (buffer + buffer_position);
        char d_type = *(buffer + buffer_position + d->d_reclen - 1);

        // skip on . and .. in the listing
        if (d->d_name[0] == '.') {
            buffer_position += d->d_reclen;
            continue;
        }

        // path = dir + '/' + name
        char path[400];
        strcpy(path, dir);
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path, d->d_name);

        // recursive call, as necessary
        if (d_type == DT_DIR)
             print_files(path, out);
        else if (d_type == DT_REG)
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", path);

        // advance buffer position
        buffer_position += d->d_reclen;

    }

    free(buffer);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char dir[1024];
    strcpy(dir, argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".");
    FILE *out = fopen("c-log.txt", "w");
    fprintf(out, "-------------[ START ]---------------------\n");
    print_files(dir, out);
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. Add some error checking for `fopen` in `main()`, Not sure about the length `char path[400]`, probably bump it up?.